”Calculus” on groups via Fox derivatives, how to generalize
I was thinking about how to do calculus on groups and came across the Fox derivatives.
For context exposition, suppose $G = \langle g_i : i \in \mathcal J \rangle$ is freely generated by elements $g_i$ indexed by indices $i$ belong to an index set $\mathcal J$. Then we define inductively the Fox partial derivatives of an element $g \in G$ with respect to a generator $g_i$, which will be denoted by
$$D_{g_i}(g) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial g_i} \in \mathbb Z[G] = \left\{ \text{functions } r \text{ with finite support, } r = \sum_g r_g g \right\}.$$
The inductive definition of $D_{g_i}$ is similar to that of a usual derivation, but instead we use a modification of Leibniz' rule,
$$\begin{cases} D_{g_i}(e) = 0 \\ D_{g_i}(g_j) =  \delta_{ij} \\ D_{g_i}(uv) = D_{g_i}(u) + u D_{g_i}(v). \end{cases}.$$
There are some interesting questions with regards to this definition: 1) what a total derivate would mean, 2) if a chain rule holds, 3) what happens if we try to extend this to any group with some presentation $G = \langle X; \, R \rangle$.
In order to answer the first question, we can attempt to define the "total Fox derivative" formally as
$$\mathrm d_g(h) = \sum_i D_{g_i}(h) \; \mathrm dg_i.$$
The question is then if this is "basis independent". Suppose that we have two bases of generators:
$$G =\langle g_i : \; i \in \mathcal J \rangle = \langle g_i' : \; i' \in \mathcal J' \rangle.$$
Then we can ask if the total derivative is invariant:
$$\mathrm dh = \sum_i D_{g_i}(h) \; \mathrm dg_i \overset{?}{=} \sum_i D_{g_i'}(h) \; \mathrm dg_i'.$$
This sparks more questions: what is $\mathrm dg$ and $D_g$ supposed to mean if $g = \prod g_i^{k_i}$ is a product of generators? Consider the toy example $G = \langle g_1, \, g_2, \, g_3 \rangle$ of a free group with 3 generators. Then let $g = g_1 g_2 g_3$, $h = g_1 g_2$, $\tilde h = g_2 g_3$. Now
$$\begin{cases}D_{g_1}(h) = 1 + 0 g_1 = 1 \\
D_{g_2}(h) = 0 + 1g_1 = g_1 \end{cases}.$$
We could also see what a formal "chain rule" would give, by treating $h$ and $\tilde h$ as generators:
$$\begin{cases} \displaystyle\frac{\mathrm dg}{\mathrm dh} = \displaystyle\frac{\mathrm d(h g_3)}{\mathrm dh} = \displaystyle\frac{\mathrm dh}{\mathrm dh} + h \displaystyle\frac{\mathrm dg_3}{\mathrm dh} = 1 \\ \\ \displaystyle\frac{\mathrm dg}{\mathrm d\tilde h} = \displaystyle\frac{\mathrm d(g_1 \tilde h)}{\mathrm d\tilde h} = \displaystyle\frac{\mathrm dg_1}{\mathrm d \tilde h} + g_1 \displaystyle\frac{\mathrm d\tilde h}{\mathrm d \tilde h} = g_1 \end{cases}.$$
Are there derivations defined with respect to an arbitrary word $g$ in a free $G$ and not just generators?
The only variant of a chain rule I could find is Fox's variant from his 1953 paper:

If $\lambda  \colon Y\to X$ is a homomorphism of free groups, then for any $f = \sum_g r_g g$ we have $\partial f^\lambda / \partial x_j=\sum_k\left(\partial f / \partial y_k\right)^\lambda \partial y_k^\lambda / \partial x_j$.

When adjoining $h$ and $\tilde h$ as generators, we actually get a slightly different group: for example $hg_3$ is not equal to $g_1 g_2 g_3$ in $G' = \langle h, \, g_i : i \in \mathcal J \rangle$. So $(h g_3)(g_1 g_2 g_3)^{-1} \neq e$. Also note that $f^\lambda$ lives in $X$, and not in $Y$.
In the case of computing $\partial(h g_3)/\partial h$, we obtain the same result as Fox's chain rule by adjoining $h$ and sending $\lambda \colon g_3 \mapsto e \in X$. Still note that the word $(h g_3^\lambda)(g_1 g_2 g_3^\lambda)^{-1} = h g_2 g_1 \neq e \in X$.
Another question is what happens when we consider the case $H = \langle X; \, R \rangle$. Intuitively we would like $D_\bullet$ to be zero on the normal subgroup that is modded away by $R$. Sadly this is not true, consider $G = \langle g_1, \, g_2 \rangle$ with $R$ consisting of $g_1 = 0$, i.e. in the quotient $g_1 = 0 \in H$.
We only need to consider the partial derivatives to see that it does not work as intended. Then $D_{g_1}(g_1) = 1$ in $G$, but we have $D_{g_1}(g_1) = D_{g_1}(0) = 0$ in $H$. So $D_\bullet$ does not seem to carry over via quotients, and therefore not to arbitrary groups (using that every group $H$ has a presentation). Is there a way to extend $D_\bullet$ in another way that makes sense and makes calculus in a group "possible"?
I am sorry if anything is not clear.

There are wayyy too many questions in this post. Please review our policy to ask one question per post, and try to whittle this down.

Does the Fox derivative truly count as "calculus on groups"? After all, the partial derivative operator of calculus does not act on elements of $\Bbb R^n$, but on functions defined on $\Bbb R^n$. The Fox derivative only counts as a derivative if $G$ is a group of functions on some set. And then it counts as doing "calculus" on the domain set, not on $G$.
